# Loop viewmodel display pattern images on select change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc, knockout-3.0

I am loading 3 selects with the following model:

```
        var viewModel = function(){
                var self = this;
                self.makes = [
                        {id: 1, name: 'Northwoods Prestige'},
                        {id:2, name: 'Forest Bay'},
                        {id:3, name: 'Timberland'}
                ];

                self.types = [
                        {id: 1, make:1, name:'Special Reserve 138', patterns:['11.jpg','12.jpg']},
                        {id: 2, make:1, name:'Special Reserve II', patterns:['13.jpg','14.jpg']},
                        {id: 3, make:2, name:'TF 138', patterns:['15.jpg','16.jpg']},
                        {id: 4, make:2, name:'TF II', patterns:['17.jpg','18.jpg']},
                        {id: 5, make:3, name:'RP 25', patterns:['19.jpg','20.jpg']},
                        {id: 6, make:3, name:'LP 25', patterns:['21.jpg','22.jpg']}
                ];

                self.models = [
                        {id:1, make:1,type: 1, name: 'Single Door'},
                        {id: 2, make:1,type: 1, name: 'Double Door'},
                        {id: 3, make:1,type: 2, name: 'Focus'},
                        {id: 5, make:2,type: 3, name: 'Q5'},
                        {id: 6, make:2,type: 3, name: 'Q7'},
                        {id: 7, make:2,type: 4, name: 'A3'},
                        {id: 8, make:2,type: 4, name: 'A4'},
                        {id: 9, make:2,type: 3, name: 'A6'}
                ];

                self.selectedMake = ko.observable();
                self.selectedType = ko.observable();
                self.selectedModel = ko.observable();

                self.carTypes = ko.computed(function(){
                        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.types, function(item){
                                return item.make === self.selectedMake();
                        });
                });

                 self.carModels = ko.computed(function(){
                        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.models, function(item){
                                return item.make === self.selectedMake() && item.type === self.selectedType();
                        });
                });
        };
        var model = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
  <div>
      <select id="make" data-bind="options: makes, value: selectedMake, optionsText : 'name', optionsValue : 'id'"></select><br/>
      <select id="type" data-bind="options: carTypes, value: selectedType, optionsText : 'name', optionsValue : 'id'"></select><br/>
      <select id="model" data-bind="options: carModels, value:selectedModel, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue : 'id'"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: carTypes, as: 'x' }">
        <div data-bind="text: x.patterns"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Whenever I change the select id="make" the model changes (foreach), I am trying to achieve this whenever I change values in select id="type" not the first one. Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `optionsCaption` to the type selector so it does not choose one by default. You may not want that, I couldn't tell.

```
<select id="type" data-bind="optionsCaption:'Select...', options: carTypes, value: selectedType, optionsText : 'name', optionsValue : 'id'"></select>
```

I created a new computed to get the entry from `carTypes` that matches the `selectedType`:

```
     self.matchingTypes = ko.computed(function () {
         var selectedType = self.selectedType();
         return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.carTypes(), function (item) {
             return item.id === selectedType;
         });
     });
```

I used that for the foreach:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: matchingTypes, as: 'x' }">
    <div data-bind="text: x.patterns"></div>
</div>
```

Now only the patterns associated with the selectedType are displayed.

To have images instead of text for the patterns, something like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: matchingTypes, as: 'x' }">
    <div data-bind="foreach: x.patterns">
        <img data-bind="attr:{src:$data}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e00suhbo/6/

Comment: Thank you, It works!. One last question before I mark it solved. As you can see in the jsfiddle the output is '11.jpg,12.jpg'. How can I generate 2 images out of that output?